# Dropbox V2 throwing "SHARED_LINK_NOT_FOUND" when trying to get shared link url

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

When picking files from the dropbox (V2), I am trying to get the shared link url using this below code.

```
  internal inner class GetDropboxSharableURLTask(file_path: String, pathLower: String) : AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
    private var pDialog: ProgressDialog? = null
    private var dropbox_url: String? = file_path
    private var db_pathLower: String? = pathLower



    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()

        pDialog = ProgressDialog(context)
        pDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
        pDialog!!.setMessage(context?.resources?.getString(R.string.please_wait))
        pDialog!!.show()
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg urls: String): Void? {
        try {

            val shareLink =   DropboxClientFactory.getClient().sharing().getSharedLinkMetadata(db_pathLower)
            dropbox_url = getShareURL(shareLink.url)!!.replaceFirst("https://www".toRegex(), "https://dl")

            return null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()

            return null
        }

    }


    fun getShareURL(strURL: String?): String? {
        var conn: URLConnection? = null
        var redirectedUrl: String? = null
        try {

            val inputURL = URL(strURL)
            conn = inputURL.openConnection()
            conn!!.connect()

            val `is` = conn.getInputStream()
            println("Redirected URL: " + conn.url)
            redirectedUrl = conn.url.toString()
            `is`.close()

        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            Log.d("", "Please input a valid URL")
        } catch (ioe: IOException) {
            Log.d("", "Can not connect to the URL")
        }

        return redirectedUrl
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(feed: Void?) {
        // TODO: check this.exception
        // TODO: do something with the feed


        pDialog!!.hide()
        Log.d("url", dropbox_url)
        val intent = Intent()

        intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_DROPBOX_PICKER, dropbox_url)

        context?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)

        context?.finish()

    }
}
```

I am getting the error as below -

> com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.SharedLinkErrorException: Exception in
>   2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata: SHARED_LINK_NOT_FOUND

This above error is thrown when calling `getSharedLinkMetadata(db_pathLower)`

Though, earlier, I was using the similar code in `dropbox V1`, but as soon as I switched to newer version of the dropbox API, i.e, `dropbox V2`, I started getting this error when trying to get the actual sharing url of dropbox, *(the one which must contain the file extension as well)*.

The expected url should be like this - `https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hpe1gjfb4aqsv3e/property_1523965639_img.jpeg?dl=0`

but, what I am getting is something like `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/AAD62_lYN5n_cYyRQWhg_rmXGJPFzqF5m8OJp‌​Nt_SIIxG7bVvmO6X5d1pKg7uulM1vEBWx_X9PZ9i3vFy-jb3eBC-M_q3YCWRmPrdAwpQ7kqSFGCIPrZaH‌​NC44YRjwXGXYTbnqMO1hPhKb-G5matDzTABUQOssB-LIN4qWoJmPnuhNgzpL9FO4ibet4uBPoef_SLZLj‌​upsOV9PKYUhtPxY_NY7HjymZSHsQh67m4HoBN4YgEAPot0KMAsV1eE3WCjK0XbD1YfGqdsVI9H40KUQ_9‌​R-nmAouoqdbA37G5CXjQKYPC8cENTvN2pjHKwCnHvgI` just because of that error.

Please, let me the know the thing, which I need to modify in order to get the dropbox sharing url (along with file extension), and to avoid the above error, as soon as the file is selected / clicked.

Comment: What is the value of `db_pathLower`? It should be an active Dropbox shared link, and if so `getSharedLinkMetadata` will return its metadata. You'll get this`SHARED_LINK_NOT_FOUND` error if the link is not valid. If you want to create a shared link for a particular file path, you should use `createSharedLinkWithSettings` instead.

Comment: @Greg I tried using `createSharedLinkWithSettings` but it gave me some error, something like, *Link already Exists* or *Shared Link already created*

Comment: If the shared link already exists, you can use `listSharedLinks` to retrieve it.

Comment: @Greg thanks a lot, finally resolved using `listSharedLinksBuilder`. Your hint somehow gave me a good sort of hint. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, resolved with the help of [this](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Get-shared-link-already-exists/m-p/187542/highlight/true#M7976), as `listSharedLinksBuilder` finally worked for me.

It got resolved by modifying the code to -

```
      val sharedLinksResults = DropboxClientFactory.getClient().sharing().listSharedLinksBuilder().withPath(db_pathLower).withDirectOnly(true).start()
        var url = ""
        if (sharedLinksResults.links.isEmpty()) {
            val shareLink = DropboxClientFactory.getClient().sharing().createSharedLinkWithSettings(db_pathLower) //.getClient().sharing().getSharedLinkMetadata(db_pathLower)
            url = shareLink.url

        } else {
            url = sharedLinksResults.links[0].url


        }
        dropbox_url = getShareURL(url)!!.replaceFirst("https://www".toRegex(), "https://dl")
```